# Why using parallelStream access and modify Collection get different result?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8

I got confused about the following code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    List<Integer> listOfIntegers =
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
    List<Integer> parallelStorage = new ArrayList<>();//Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    listOfIntegers
            .parallelStream()
            // Don't do this! It uses a stateful lambda expression.
            .map(e -> {
                parallelStorage.add(e);
                return e;
            })
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    System.out.println();
    parallelStorage
            .stream()
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sleep 5 sec");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    parallelStorage
            .stream()
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
}
```

EveryTime execute it I got different result which really confused me a lot ,
here are some results :

```
Result 1:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
null 3 8 7 1 4 5 6 
Sleep 5 sec
null 3 8 7 1 4 5 6

Result 2：
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
6 2 4 1 5 7 8 
Sleep 5 sec
6 2 4 1 5 7 8
```

Here are two problems:

- Q1: Why the size of parallelStorage is uncertain?

  I understand parallelStream using fork/join framework, so I guess the problem is caused by some thread who doesn't finish their job, then I paused the main thread for 5 seconds, but seems no help, the size of parallelStorage still kept unchanged;
- Q2: Why null elements exist in parallelStorage?

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html): `Aggregate operations and parallel streams enable you to implement parallelism with non-thread-safe collections provided that you do not modify the collection while you are operating on it.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ArrayList` is not thread-safe.  That means that if you have two threads updating the list simultaneously, the two threads could interfere which each other in ways that could cause loss of data (or, for some data structures, could entirely corrupt the structure).

I don't know the exact sequence of steps that gets taken when you add to an `ArrayList`, but let's say it's something like this.  An `ArrayList` should contain a backing array, and an instance variable that indicates what the current size is

- Read the array size into local variable `N`
- Put the new element in `arr[N]`
- Add 1 to `N`
- Store `N` back in the array size

Now suppose you have two threads doing this.  Since there is no synchronization, the threads could take the steps in this order, if they both call `add` at the same time:

```
Read the array size into N
                                    Read the array size into N
Put the new element in arr[N]
                                    Put the new element in arr[N]
Add 1 to N 
                                    Add 1 to N
Store N into the array size
                                    Store N into the array size
```

If the array size is 3 before either thread calls `add`, note that both threads will read 3 into their own local variable `N`; then they'll both put the new element in the same place, and then will both store 4 into the array size.  So even though two elements were "added", the new array size will be 4 and not 5, and one of the new data elements will be lost.

That's why you need a synchronized list.

(The way the steps are done between the multiple threads is unpredictable.  So it's believable that in some cases, a different order of execution could lead to the size being incremented by both threads before an element is stored, causing an element in the array to remain unused and therefore be `null`.  Please don't take the sequence of steps I posted here as the actual steps taken by the Java runtime; it's just an example, and I didn't look at the `ArrayList` code.)

Comment: notice that using `Collections.synchronizedList` will not preserve order. The only guarantee is that *all* elements will be collected (there will be no nulls for example); but the order is still broken in the `parallelStorage`

Comment: Java 8’s `ArrayList` defers the creation of the backing array to the point when the first element is added. So when two or more threads try to add the first element, multiple arrays might get created, which can lead to `null` elements at the beginning, even without visibility or reordering issues. The other issues might arise (or become worse), when the program runs longer than a few nanoseconds…

Comment: @Eugene Right.  I was trying to answer the questions about why the size was inconsistent, and why there were nulls in the array--not about the order.

Answer (score 4):

You *have* written yourself - this is a *stateful* lambda and these should be avoided. `ArrayList` is indeed not thread-safe and collecting to such a `List` will break things in an un-expcted way. Especially when the list needs to double it's size internally and copy elements. Generally there is no way to judge what will happen (or if it happens with such non thread-safe collection).

But even adding `Collections.synchronizedList` is still wrong, since it does not preserve order (in case you care). The only guarantee that you have is that *all* elements will be collected indeed, but in *an out-of-order way*.

```
    Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(intArray));
    List<Integer> parallelStorage = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>(1));
    listOfIntegers
            .parallelStream()
            // Don't do this! It uses a stateful lambda expression.
            .map(e -> {
                parallelStorage.add(e);
                return e;
            })
            .forEachOrdered(e -> System.out.print(e + " "));
    System.out.println(parallelStorage);
```

The only thing you know for sure is that `parallelStorage` will indeed have all the elements from `listOfIntegers` (as opposed to the plain `ArrayList` where you saw a null); but otherwise the order will still be broken.

You could easily see results like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 [3, 8, 5, 2, 7, 1, 4, 6]
```

`forEachOrdered` preserves encounter order (if it is not broken by other intermediate operations, say `unordered` for example), but this order is preserved only for `forEachOrdered`, it does not mean that elements are still *processed* in the encounter order.